# Why do negative charge parity exchanges couple differently to proton and antiproton?

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model

Why do negative charge parity exchanges such as $\rho$, $\omega$ couple differently in sign to proton and antiproton?

One encounters a scattering amplitude with two components when studying proton-proton and proton-antiproton elastic scattering. One of the components corresponds to a positive charge parity exchange that does not change sign when going from proton-proton to proton-antiproton process, while the other corresponds to a negative charge parity exchange that changes the sign.

For example

[image]

(from V. Barone, E. Predazzi, High-Energy Particle Diffraction, Springer 2002)

What is the reason behind this?

Comment: Can you add context?

Comment: Describe it thoroughly with details of what you're talking about

Answer (score 2):

The interactions are strong, interactions that preserve C.

So the "target" vertex parts of the exchange diagram  in the two reactions must differ by a sign,
$$C|p\rangle  = |\bar p \rangle  , \qquad 
C|\bar p\rangle = | p \rangle  , \qquad 
C \rho C^{-1} =C\rho C=-\rho \leadsto \\
\langle p| \rho|p\rangle =\langle\bar  p| C\rho C|\bar p\rangle =-\langle \bar p|  \rho   |\bar p\rangle,
$$
and likewise for all odd C intermediator particles.

PS: The use of the ~ symbol in your question to mean "t-channel" exchange meson/Pomeron  vertex is particularly unfortunate and confusing to most readers not appreciating you are referring to the "lower vertex of the tree diagram"...